# How can I troubleshoot this MySQL Foreign Key Constraint Fails error? The data looks right

Tags: mysql

I'm finding it difficult to localize this error in MySQL. I have a table called "community" and another called "message". The "message" table has a foreign key column called "to_community_id". I have several communities in the "community" table. When I try to insert messages with some community ids (which are valid,) the query fails with a "Foreign Key Constraint Fails" error. Some community ids work. The rest of the data of the communities is exactly the same. What could be causing this error?

Schemas:

```
Community:
FIELD       TYPE            NULL    KEY     EXTRA
id          int(10) unsignedNO      PRI     auto_increment
name        varchar(255)    YES         
address     varchar(255)    YES         
city        varchar(255)    YES         
country     varchar(255)    YES         
phone       varchar(255)    YES         
coordinates point           YES         
data        json            YES         
settings    json            YES         
private     tinyint(1)      YES         
deleted tinyint(1)          YES     



Message:

FIELD               TYPE               NULL KEY EXTRA
id                  int(10) unsigned    NO   PRI auto_increment
datetime            datetime            YES         
deleted             tinyint(1)          YES     
read                tinyint(1)          YES     
details             json                YES         
from_user_id        int(10) unsigned    YES 
to_user_id          int(10) unsigned    YES         
from_community_id   int(10) unsigned    YES     
to_community_id     int(10) unsigned    YES     
community_join_id   int(10) unsigned    YES
```

Foreign key constraints:

```
CONSTRAINT_NAME                            TABLE_NAME   CONSTRAINT_TYPE
message_community_join_request_id_foreign   message     FOREIGN KEY
message_from_community_id_foreign           message     FOREIGN KEY
message_from_user_id_foreign                message     FOREIGN KEY
message_to_community_id_foreign             message     FOREIGN KEY
message_to_user_id_foreign                  message     FOREIGN KEY
```

Insert statement:

```
insert into message (`from_user_id`,  `to_community_id`, `to_user_id`) 
values ( 1, 11, 2);
```

Comment: You'll need to provide schemas and `INSERT`s that reproduce the problem, before we can say anything.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: You didn't define any foreign keys in that schema, and you only insert into one table. Please provide a proper [mcve] if you want help. We're not going to guess. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I will answer my own question because, even though this answer makes me look like an idiot, it may help others in the same boat.

Looking at the foreign keys closely, I noticed that the referenced table of the "to_community_id" field was wrong.

Fixing it resolved the issue.